# How to remove # from hashtag using Python RegEx

Tags: regex, python-re, hashtag

My requirement is to remove leading "#" symbol from hashtags in a text. For example, sentence: `I'm feeling #blessed.` should transform to `I'm feeling blessed.`

I have written this function, but I'm sure I can achieve the same with a simpler logic in RegEx.

```
  clean_sentence = ""
  space = " "
  for token in sentence.split():
    if token[0] is '#':
      token = token[1:]
    clean_sentence += token + space
  return clean_sentence
```

Need help here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex provided by by @Tim `#(\S+)` would also match hashtags in non-starting position if they have another non-whitespace character `\S` behind them, e.g. as in `so#blessed`.

We can prevent this by adding a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` before the hash, so that it can't be preceded by anything that is not a whitespace.

```
inp = "#I'm #feeling #blessed so#blessed .#here#."
output = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)#(\S+)', r'\1', inp)
print(output)
```

output:

```
I'm feeling blessed so#blessed .#here#.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.sub` as follows:

```py
inp = "I'm feeling #blessed."
output = re.sub(r'#(\S+)', r'\1', inp)
print(output)  # I'm feeling blessed.
```

Comment: funnily it only works on some text when used in a function. Must be a formatting issue of the input